# spring boot with thymeleaf html table with class model array

Tags: spring-boot, spring-thymeleaf, spring-json

I got this class model (I made it only 2 column),

```
public class DataModel {


    private int id;
    private String name;
    public DataModel() {}

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Here's the data.json,

```
[
 {
    "id":1,
    "name":"Bill",
 },
 {
    "id":2,
    "name":"Steve",
 }
]
```

Here's the controller class on the @PostConstruct(take 2-3 hours for figuring out the can't resolve json),

```
    @PostConstruct
    private void loadData() {
        // load json
        String strJson = null;
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("json/data.json");
        try {
            byte[] binaryData = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(classPathResource.getInputStream());
            strJson = new String(binaryData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // setup array mapper
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        DataModel[] datawiz;
        try {
            datawiz = objectMapper.readValue(strJson, DataModel[].class);
            // this print the first array on the json
            System.out.println("Id = " + datawiz[0].getId() + " & Name = " + datawiz[0].getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

There's no problem there.
How do I use it in thymeleaf html?
I got only example like this,

```
        // create menu list
        DataModel menulist1 = new DataModel(1, "Bill");
        DataModel menulist2 = new DataModel(2, "Steve");        

        // create the list
        theData = new ArrayList<>();

         add to the list
        theData.add(menulist1);
        theData.add(menulist2);
        
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listMenu(Model theModel) {

        // add to the spring model
        theModel.addAttribute("thelist", theData);

        return "menu-list";
```

I can't do this theData=datawiz (of course removing those example with menulist* and *.add*).

Then on the menu-list.html,

```
    <table>

        <tbody>
            <tr th:each="theList : ${thelist}">
            
                <td th:text="${theList.id}" />  
                <td th:text="${theList.name}" />    
                
            </tr>
        </tbody>        
    </table>
```

Tried this,

```
        for(DataModel dataw : datawiz[]) {
            theData.add(dataw);
        }
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking to use simple "for" like in phyton (I'm a previous snake coder) but the old tricks did it,

```
        for(int i = 0; i < datawiz.length; i++) {
            DataModel dat = new DataModel(datawiz[i].getId(),datawiz[i].getName());
            theDatawiz.add(dat);
        }
```